# R package VLMC dies if state space size exceeds 27

Tags: r, markov-chains

I am using VLMC to fit some Markov models and it dies as soon as the alphabet size reaches 28.
I thought this was due to using a single letter in the alphabet by default, but it has the same behavior with "code1char = FALSE".  This is true for me on real data as well as this fake example.

```
library(VLMC)

# works fine
ins <- sample(seq(1,27,1),50000,replace=T)
vlmc(ins, dump = 1,threshold.gen = 2, debug = TRUE)

#core dump
ins <- sample(seq(1,28,1),50000,replace=T)
vlmc(ins, dump = 1,threshold.gen = 2, debug = TRUE)
```

Any ideas?

The seg fault looks like this BTW.  It looks to me like the alphabet after z is being mapped to NA which is causing an array bound issue.

```
library(VLMC)

sc <- 10
amp <- 13
x <- round(amp*sin(seq(0,2*sc*pi,0.01)))
x <- amp + x + rpois(NROW(x),1)
length(table(x))
length(x)

vlmc(x, dump = 1,threshold.gen = 2, debug = TRUE)

vlmc: Alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzNANANANANA' ; |X| = 31
vlmc: ctl.dump =  4 11 
vlmc: n = |data| = 6284, cutoff{prune} = 21.8865, threshold{gen} = 2
vlmc: |alphabet| = 31, alphabet = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzNA
generating... 
*** caught segfault ***
  address 0x0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
  1: .C("vlmc_p", data = Data, n = n, threshold.gen = as.integer(threshold.gen),     cutoff.prune = as.double(cutoff.prune), alpha.len = as.integer(alpha.len),     alpha = as.character(Alpha), debug = as.integer(as.logical(debug)),     dump.flags = as.integer(c(dump, ctl.dump)), size = integer(4),     PACKAGE = "VLMC")
2: vlmc(x, dump = 1, threshold.gen = 2, debug = TRUE)
```

Comment: sounds like an email to `maintainer(VLMC)` is in order (assuming this isn't documented in the function somewhere).

Comment: R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0/x86_64 (64-bit)

Comment: If you look more carefully, you will see that also the |X| = 27 is not quite ok.  The limit is currently really at 26.   We hadn't seen a case of more than very few letters..  But yes, several years later, I agree that this was too lazy programming (("nobody will ever use much larger state spaces"... what a silly hope !))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the maintainer of VLMC,
I can tell you that one of the longest standing  TODO  entries for VLMC has been to raise the currently *builtin* limit of 26 for the maximal alphabet size should be raised..

Of course it it is a bug that I don't give an error message in the case of a larger alphabet, but rather pass things to C and do not check there.
The next version of VLMC will not seg.fault for this anymore.

However, I'm not yet sure I'll find the time to allow a considerably larger alphabet....
Of course I'd happily accept patches ... it's free open source software.

Best regards, 
Martin Maechler, ETH Zurich

Comment: Thanks!  Naively it seems like a small change. I''ll take a crack it it.

Comment: well, as I wrote you privately, the really small change just increases the maximal size (and costs memory and hence speed for small alphabets).  The real solution is a bit more work.

Comment: Thanks again Martin. I'll put some thought into it.  My first thought is to provide a switch that does the "dumb" thing and increases the maximal size to a user-specified level.  There can be ample warnings about the performance implications for small alphabets when that option is used.